# adding an integer postfix or prefix to an html attribute with flask-wtforms

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I have the following thing in a jinja2 for loop:

```
{{ meal[item]['open-modal'].submit(**{ 'class':'btn btn-primary',
                                        'data-toggle':'modal', 
                                        'data-target':'#myModal' }) }}
```

I need to have an index on the data-target like:

```
{{ meal[item]['open-modal'].submit(**{ 'class':'btn btn-primary', 
                                        'data-toggle':'modal', 
                                        'data-target':'#myModal-item' }) }}
```

`item` is the index needed in this case. Is there a way to escape `item` out of this ["ad-hoc dictionary"](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/107/)? So that it takes on the same values as in `meal[item]`?

I need the `'data-target'` attribute to render as `'#myModal-0'`, `'#myModal-1'`, etc.. As it stands each `'data-target'` attribute gets set as `'#myModal-item'` for each item in the loop. In other words it sets item in the second line of code as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it is ever helpful for someone, what wound up solving my problem was:

```
<form method="POST">
    {{ meal[item]['open-modal'].csrf_token }}
    {{ meal[item]['open-modal'].submit( **{ 'class':'btn btn-primary',
                                            'data-toggle':'modal',
                                            'data-target':'#myModal-' + 
                                                          item|string } ) }}
</form>
```

Keep in mind that this is nested inside of two for loops in jinja2.

```
{% for meal in menu_dict %}
{% for item in meal %}
    ....
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The point is summarized with this, basically:

```
'data-target':'#myModal-' + item|string
```

adds the postfix.

Comment: 5 years later. This helped me today. Thanks man :)